# How can I show Oultook 2016 calendar appointments on win10 lock screen?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, lock-screen

In a company setting, how a user can show Oultook 2016 calendar appointments on win 10 lock screen?

EDIT: Ideally, the solution would use outlook directly. (and not use win 10 Calendar app)